# Convey 2 meanings in one sentence correctly

Tags: phrase-requests, meaning-in-context, ambiguity, emphasis

The sentence is

*"Tom was the first ever student from Jacksonville University to qualify for the prestigious math competition, while only being in his sophomore year"*

What i what to emphasise is that Tom managed to qualify for the competition while still being only in his sophomore year. As in, he was really young but still managed to qualify - this means he possessed an advanced skillset.

However, the given sentence can also be interpreted as Tom was the only person to qualify for the competition from the Sophomore year - e.i there are more people from other years who qualified.

I'm not sure how I can correctly put the point forward, would really appreciate some help!

Comment: Advice on the best wording for a piece of writing is off-topic on this site, but this question would be on-topic at our other site [writing.se]. I'm flagging this question for migration to that site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can put "*while only being in his sophomore year,*" in the beginning of the sentence as an **introductory dependent clause** so that it becomes much clearer that you want to emphasize that Tom still managed to qualify despite being a sophomore.

> While only being in his sophomore year, Tom was the first ever student from Jacksonville University to qualify for the prestigious math competition.

You can also do the following:

> Tom, despite being only a sophomore, was the first ever student from Jacksonville University to qualify for the prestigious math competition.

The trick here, for me, is to put the modifying clause as close to the subject/object as possible to avoid any confusion on which word or words are actually being referred to.

Comment: Phrase 1 is what I went with. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

TOM, a sophomore, is the first student at Jacksonville university to qualify for the PRESTIOUS MATH COMPETITION.

Comment: Correction: Tom, a sophmore, is the first student at Jackson University to acheive the Prestigious Math. Competition.

Comment: Hi Betty, welcome to our site. It looks like you've recognised that the all-caps is undesirable (much better to use **bold** or *italic* font for emphasis). However, you need to amend your answer directly rather than adding a comment. You can do this using the [edit] link. Note also that it's not sufficient just to give the solution, you should also add a paragraph explaining *why* this works best. For further guidance, see [answer], and don't forget to take the **[Tour]** :-)